# Shiny: Automatic SelectInput Value Update Based on Previous Filter

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am creating a shiny app. The goal is to create a custom filter initially from a dataset. After creating that filter, I want the options from one of the columns to dynamically change in the selectInput tab. The problem I am having is that when I reference the new dataset in the ui section of the shiny app, it doesn't recognize that dataframe. Below are my ui and server parts that work but I need to manually add the selectInput values. I want it to change automatically.

Original App:

ui

```
# ui.R

library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Language Selection"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("The goal from this is to have the select tab automatically update with the language after selecting the artist"),

      helpText("Select your artist"),

      textInput("artistId", "Artist", value = "", width = NULL, 
            placeholder = NULL),

      actionButton("goButton", "Submit Artist"),

      helpText("Based on the artist you selected, now select the Language below to display the numberlist in the main panel."),

      selectInput("selectinputid", "Language to Select:", choices = c("English" = "English", "French" = "French", "German" = "German")),
      ##selectInput("selectinputid", "Language to Select:", choices = artist_filter_complete$Language),
      actionButton("goButton1", "Submit Language")),
mainPanel(
        tableOutput("result")
      )
    )
  ))
```

server

```
##server
library(shiny)

Artist <- c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
            "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", 
            "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3")

Language <- c("Spanish", "Spanish", "Spanish", "Spanish", "Spanish", "German", "German", "German", "French", "French", "French", "French",
              "Italian", "Italian", "Italian", "Italian", "Italian", "Polish", "Polish", "Polish", "Israeli", "Israeli", "Israeli", "Israeli",
              "English", "English", "English", "English", "English", "Armenian", "Armenian", "Armenian", "Bengali", "Bengali", "Bengali", "Bengali")

NumberList <- c("uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco", "einz", "zwei", "drei", "un", "deux", "trois", "quatre",
                "uno", "due", "tre", "quattro", "cinque", "jeden", "dwa", "trzy", "achat", "shtaim", "shalosh", "arba",
                "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "mek", "yerku", "yerek", "shoonno", "ek", "dui", "tin")

df <- data.frame(Artist, Language, NumberList)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$result <- renderTable({
    randomVals <- eventReactive(input$goButton, input$artistId)
    artist_filter <- c(randomVals())
    artist_filter_complete <- filter(df, Artist == artist_filter)
    randomVals2 <- eventReactive(input$goButton1, input$selectinputid)
    target <- c(randomVals2())
    result_final<-filter(artist_filter_complete, Language %in% target)
    result_final
  })
}
)
```

This is what my output looks like:

[image]

How do I make the language selectInput automatically/dynamically change with all the possible languages **with only that artist that I type in initially**? My attempt is commented out in the ui section but when I run it calling:

```
##selectInput("selectinputid", "Language to Select:", choices = artist_filter_complete$Language),
```

It states that it cannot find that dataframe: `artist_filter_complete`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I changed a few things here and removed a few buttons, which I dont think are necessary here, have a look yourself and see if it makes sense to you:

```
library(shiny)

Artist <- c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
            "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", 
            "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3")

Language <- c("Spanish", "Spanish", "Spanish", "Spanish", "Spanish", "German", "German", "German", "French", "French", "French", "French",
              "Italian", "Italian", "Italian", "Italian", "Italian", "Polish", "Polish", "Polish", "Israeli", "Israeli", "Israeli", "Israeli",
              "English", "English", "English", "English", "English", "Armenian", "Armenian", "Armenian", "Bengali", "Bengali", "Bengali", "Bengali")

NumberList <- c("uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco", "einz", "zwei", "drei", "un", "deux", "trois", "quatre",
                "uno", "due", "tre", "quattro", "cinque", "jeden", "dwa", "trzy", "achat", "shtaim", "shalosh", "arba",
                "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "mek", "yerku", "yerek", "shoonno", "ek", "dui", "tin")

df <- data.frame(Artist, Language, NumberList)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Language Selection"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        helpText("The goal from this is to have the select tab automatically update with the language after selecting the artist"),

        helpText("Select artistId artist"),
        selectInput("artistId", "Artist", choices = unique(df$Artist)),
        helpText("Based on the artist you selected, now select the Language below to display the numberlist in the main panel."),

        selectInput("selectinputid", "Language to Select:", choices = unique(df$Language)),
        actionButton("goButton1", "Submit Language")),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("result")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  observeEvent(D1(),{
    updateSelectInput(session, "selectinputid", "Language to Select:",  choices = unique(D1()$Language),selected = unique(D1()$Language)[1])
  })

  D1  <- reactive({
    df[df$Artist %in% input$artistId,]
  })

  D2 <- eventReactive(input$goButton1,{
    D1()[D1()$Language %in% input$selectinputid,]
  })

  output$result <- renderTable({
    D2()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Edit: modify to text input by request**

```
library(shiny)

Artist <- c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
            "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", 
            "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3")

Language <- c("Spanish", "Spanish", "Spanish", "Spanish", "Spanish", "German", "German", "German", "French", "French", "French", "French",
              "Italian", "Italian", "Italian", "Italian", "Italian", "Polish", "Polish", "Polish", "Israeli", "Israeli", "Israeli", "Israeli",
              "English", "English", "English", "English", "English", "Armenian", "Armenian", "Armenian", "Bengali", "Bengali", "Bengali", "Bengali")

NumberList <- c("uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco", "einz", "zwei", "drei", "un", "deux", "trois", "quatre",
                "uno", "due", "tre", "quattro", "cinque", "jeden", "dwa", "trzy", "achat", "shtaim", "shalosh", "arba",
                "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "mek", "yerku", "yerek", "shoonno", "ek", "dui", "tin")

df <- data.frame(Artist, Language, NumberList)

ui <- shinyUI(
        fluidPage(
                titlePanel("Language Selection"),
                sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                                helpText("The goal from this is to have the select tab automatically update with the language after selecting the artist"),

                                helpText("Select artistId artist"),
                                textInput("artistId", "Artist", value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = NULL),
                                helpText("Based on the artist you selected, now select the Language below to display the numberlist in the main panel."),

                                selectInput("selectinputid", "Language to Select:", choices = unique(df$Language)),
                                actionButton("goButton1", "Submit Language")),
                        mainPanel(
                                tableOutput("result")
                        )
                )
        )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

        observeEvent(D1(),{
                updateSelectInput(session, "selectinputid", "Language to Select:",  choices = unique(D1()$Language),selected = unique(D1()$Language)[1])
        })

        D1  <- reactive({
                df[df$Artist %in% input$artistId,]
        })

        D2 <- eventReactive(input$goButton1,{
                D1()[D1()$Language %in% input$selectinputid,]
        })

        output$result <- renderTable({
                D2()
        })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like I need to make a few changes to my original.

Comment: Would you be able to modify this so that the first one is a textInput rather than a selectInput?

Comment: Last question from this, ( I can make this into another question if you'd like too if it would take too long). Let's say from our textInput, we write "A1". That A1 is then placed into a function within the server part of this question to retrieve a dataset via API. Because this part needs to be in the server section and we do not know what the initial dataset looks like until we make that "A1" call, is it possible to still reference that dataset in the ui part (unique(df$Artist)

Comment: Just posted a follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352515/reactive-selectinput-dataset-unknown-until-api-call-from-previous-filter

Comment: I think you may need a `,` after the `textInput` line