# Reactive SelectInput (Dataset Unknown until API call from Previous Filter)

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am creating a shiny app that will do the following using Spotify's API:

1) You manually type in the Artist Name

**2) In the selectInput, the albums need to automatically populate for your selection.**

3) After selecting the album, a table in the main panel will show the songs, artist, and album.

I have this working so far but I cannot figure out how to do the 2nd part which is to automatically populate the albums once the artist is selected. I asked a previous question here: [Shiny: Automatic SelectInput Value Update Based on Previous Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46348193/shiny-automatic-selectinput-value-update-based-on-previous-filter) but I realized that after asking the question, the dataset will not be known in the beginning for you to reference in the ui.

So instead of doing this:

```
selectInput("selectinputid", "Album #1 to Select:", choices = c("Yeezus" = "Yeezus", "Graduation" = "Graduation", "Gears" = "gear"))
```

I want to do this:

```
selectInput("selectinputid", "Album #1 to Select:", choices = unique(with_album_name$`Album Name`)
```

Here is the code:

```
# ui.R

library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Spotify: Interactive Song Selection"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("The goal from this is for you to compare two artists' albums and see how similar the songs are based on the audio features."),

      helpText("Select your first artist you want to compare. For example: ",
           tags$b("Kanye West")),

      textInput("albumId", "Artist Name #1", value = "", width = NULL, 
            placeholder = NULL),

      actionButton("goButton", "Submit Both Artists"),

      helpText("Based on the artist you selected, now select the albums that you want to compare songs for."),

      selectInput("selectinputid", "Album #1 to Select:", choices = c("Yeezus" = "Yeezus", "Graduation" = "Graduation", "Gears" = "gear")),

      actionButton("goButton1", "Submit Both Albums")),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("result")
    )
  )
))
```

Server Section:

```
# server.R

spotifyKey <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
spotifySecret <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

library("httr")
library("jsonlite")
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)

response = POST(
  'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
  accept_json(),
  authenticate(spotifyKey, spotifySecret),
  body = list(grant_type = 'client_credentials'),
  encode = 'form',
  verbose()
 )

token = content(response)$access_token

HeaderValue = paste0('Bearer ', token)

library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$result <- renderTable({
    randomVals <- eventReactive(input$goButton, input$albumId)
    spotify <- c(randomVals())

    ##Retrieve Artist ID

    get.artist <- function(spotify){
      artistnameURL <- paste("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=", spotify, "&type=artist", sep="")
      getArtist <- GET(artistnameURL, add_headers(Authorization = HeaderValue))
      artistname <- jsonlite::fromJSON(toJSON(content(getArtist)))
      ids <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(artistname$artists$items$id), 
                           nrow=artistname$artists$total, 
byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      names <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(artistname$artists$items$name), 
                             nrow=artistname$artists$total, 
byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      colnames(ids)[1]<-"Artist ID"
      colnames(names)[1]<-"Artist Name"
      artist_search <- cbind(names, ids)
      artist_search <- artist_search[1,]
      return(artist_search)
    }

    df1 <- lapply(spotify, get.artist)
    result2 <- do.call(rbind, df1)
    result2_final<-result2
    ids<-result2_final$`Artist ID`

    ##Retrieve Artist Albums

    get.albums <- function(ids){
      artists_albumsURL <- paste("https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/", ids, "/albums", sep="")
      getArtistAlbum <- GET(artists_albumsURL, add_headers(Authorization = HeaderValue))
      artistalbumname <- jsonlite::fromJSON(toJSON(content(getArtistAlbum)))
      albumids <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(artistalbumname$items$id), 
                                nrow=artistalbumname$total, 
byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      albumnames <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(artistalbumname$items$name), 
                                  nrow=artistalbumname$total, 
byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      artistid2 <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(artistalbumname$items$artists[[1]]$id), 
                                 nrow=artistalbumname$total, 
byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      artistname2 <- 
data.frame(matrix(unlist(artistalbumname$items$artists[[1]]$name), 
                                   nrow=artistalbumname$total, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

      colnames(albumids)[1]<-"Album IDs"
      colnames(albumnames)[1]<-"Album Name"
      colnames(artistid2)[1]<-"Artist ID"
      colnames(artistname2[1])<-"Artist Name"
      album_search <- cbind(artistid2, artistname2, albumnames, albumids)
      album_search <- unique(album_search)
      return(album_search)
    }

    df <- lapply(ids, get.albums)

    result <- do.call(rbind, df)
    result_final<-result
    colnames(result_final)[2]<-"Artist Name"
    spotify<-result_final$`Album IDs`

    get.tracks <- function(spotify){
      albumTracksURL <- paste("https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/", spotify, "/tracks?limit=50", sep="")
      getTracks <- GET(albumTracksURL, add_headers(Authorization = HeaderValue))
      albumTracks <- jsonlite::fromJSON(toJSON(content(getTracks)))

      ids <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(albumTracks$items$id), 
                           nrow=albumTracks$total, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

      names <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(albumTracks$items$name), 
                             nrow=albumTracks$total, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      artists<-albumTracks$items$artists
      artists1<-do.call(rbind, lapply(artists, function(x) do.call(cbind, lapply(x[c('id', 'name')], toString))))

      result <- cbind(ids, names, artists1)

      colnames(result) <- c("ID", "NAME", "ARTIST ID", "ARTIST NAME")
      result$AlbumID <- spotify
      return(result)
    }

    df <- lapply(spotify, get.tracks)

    result <- do.call(rbind, df)
    result_final2<-result

    names(result_final2) <- c("ID", "NAME", "ARTIST ID", "ARTIST NAME")
    final<-result_final2

    final1<-final[!duplicated(final), ]

    final2 <- final1[!duplicated(final1[2:5]),]
    colnames(final2)[5]<-"Album ID"

    with_album_name<-left_join(final2,result_final, by=c("Album ID" = "Album IDs"))
    with_album_name <- with_album_name[,-c(6:7)]

    ##target <- c(input$selectinputid)
    randomVals2 <- eventReactive(input$goButton1, input$selectinputid)
    target <- c(randomVals2())
    result_final<-filter(with_album_name, `Album Name` %in% target)
    final2<-result_final
    final2
   })})
```

Output:

[image]

In the ui part, I need to find a way to reference the `with_album_name` table, but that table is created in the server section. Not sure how this can be done because right now all I have is to manually put in the album names for selection and that will not work when I want to reference a different artist in the spotify database.

Comment: are you asking how to update `output$result`?

Comment: Nope, I'm asking how to update the selectInput tab: "Album #1 to Select:" Currently, I am manually inputting "Yeezus", "Graduation", etc. but I want this to dynamically change to all the available albums from the artist that is typed in manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overwrote your server part:

- moved all functions out of it (I prefer to keep my server function in a separate file);
- Restructured server code: all code was returning single table. I now added `observeEvent` to update list

Minor changes in `selectInput` part:

```
  selectInput("selectinputid", "Album #1 to Select:", "")
```

Server part:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    ids <- reactive({
        randomVals <- eventReactive(input$goButton, input$albumId)
        spotify <- c(randomVals())
        df1 <- lapply(spotify, get.artist)
        result2 <- do.call(rbind, df1)
        result2_final<-result2
        result2_final$`Artist ID`
    })

    result_final <- reactive({
        df <- lapply(ids(), get.albums)
        result <- do.call(rbind, df)
        colnames(result)[2]<-"Artist Name"
        result
    })

   # Observes and updates album selection part
   observe({
        albums <- unique(result_final()$`Album Name`)
        updateSelectInput(session, "selectinputid",
                          label = "selectinputid",
                          choices = albums,
                          selected = albums[1])
    })

    output$result <- renderTable({
        spotify<-result_final()$`Album IDs`
        df <- lapply(spotify, get.tracks)
        result <- do.call(rbind, df)
        result_final2<-result
        names(result_final2) <- c("ID", "NAME", "ARTIST ID", "ARTIST NAME")
        final<-result_final2
        final1<-final[!duplicated(final), ]    
        final2 <- final1[!duplicated(final1[2:5]),]
        colnames(final2)[5]<-"Album ID"    
        with_album_name<-left_join(final2,result_final(), by=c("Album ID" = "Album IDs"))
        with_album_name <- with_album_name[,-c(6:7)] 
        randomVals2 <- eventReactive(input$goButton1, input$selectinputid)
        target <- c(randomVals2())
        result_final<-filter(with_album_name, `Album Name` %in% target)
        final2<-result_final
        final2
    })
}
```

All code (messy):

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Spotify: Interactive Song Selection"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("The goal from this is for you to compare two artists' albums and see how similar the songs are based on the audio features."),

      helpText("Select your first artist you want to compare. For example: ",
           tags$b("Kanye West")),

      textInput("albumId", "Artist Name #1", value = "", width = NULL, 
            placeholder = NULL),

      actionButton("goButton", "Submit Both Artists"),

      helpText("Based on the artist you selected, now select the albums that you want to compare songs for."),

       selectInput("selectinputid", "Album #1 to Select:", ""),

      actionButton("goButton1", "Submit Both Albums")),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("result")
    )
  )
)


spotifyKey <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
spotifySecret <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

library("httr")
library("jsonlite")
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)

response = POST(
  'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
  accept_json(),
  authenticate(spotifyKey, spotifySecret),
  body = list(grant_type = 'client_credentials'),
  encode = 'form',
  verbose()
 )

token = content(response)$access_token

HeaderValue = paste0('Bearer ', token)

    get.artist <- function(spotify){
      artistnameURL <- paste("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=", spotify, "&type=artist", sep="")
      getArtist <- GET(artistnameURL, add_headers(Authorization = HeaderValue))
      artistname <- jsonlite::fromJSON(toJSON(content(getArtist)))
      ids <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(artistname$artists$items$id), 
                           nrow=artistname$artists$total, 
byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      names <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(artistname$artists$items$name), 
                             nrow=artistname$artists$total, 
byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      colnames(ids)[1]<-"Artist ID"
      colnames(names)[1]<-"Artist Name"
      artist_search <- cbind(names, ids)
      artist_search <- artist_search[1,]
      return(artist_search)
    }




    get.albums <- function(ids){
      artists_albumsURL <- paste("https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/", ids, "/albums", sep="")
      getArtistAlbum <- GET(artists_albumsURL, add_headers(Authorization = HeaderValue))
      artistalbumname <- jsonlite::fromJSON(toJSON(content(getArtistAlbum)))
      albumids <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(artistalbumname$items$id), 
                                nrow=artistalbumname$total, 
byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      albumnames <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(artistalbumname$items$name), 
                                  nrow=artistalbumname$total, 
byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      artistid2 <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(artistalbumname$items$artists[[1]]$id), 
                                 nrow=artistalbumname$total, 
byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      artistname2 <- 
data.frame(matrix(unlist(artistalbumname$items$artists[[1]]$name), 
                                   nrow=artistalbumname$total, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

      colnames(albumids)[1]<-"Album IDs"
      colnames(albumnames)[1]<-"Album Name"
      colnames(artistid2)[1]<-"Artist ID"
      colnames(artistname2[1])<-"Artist Name"
      album_search <- cbind(artistid2, artistname2, albumnames, albumids)
      album_search <- unique(album_search)
      return(album_search)
    }


    get.tracks <- function(spotify){
      albumTracksURL <- paste("https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/", spotify, "/tracks?limit=50", sep="")
      getTracks <- GET(albumTracksURL, add_headers(Authorization = HeaderValue))
      albumTracks <- jsonlite::fromJSON(toJSON(content(getTracks)))

      ids <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(albumTracks$items$id), 
                           nrow=albumTracks$total, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

      names <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(albumTracks$items$name), 
                             nrow=albumTracks$total, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      artists<-albumTracks$items$artists
      artists1<-do.call(rbind, lapply(artists, function(x) do.call(cbind, lapply(x[c('id', 'name')], toString))))

      result <- cbind(ids, names, artists1)

      colnames(result) <- c("ID", "NAME", "ARTIST ID", "ARTIST NAME")
      result$AlbumID <- spotify
      return(result)
    }


server <- function(input, output, session) {
    ids <- reactive({
        randomVals <- eventReactive(input$goButton, input$albumId)
        spotify <- c(randomVals())
        df1 <- lapply(spotify, get.artist)
        result2 <- do.call(rbind, df1)
        result2_final<-result2
        result2_final$`Artist ID`
    })

    result_final <- reactive({
        df <- lapply(ids(), get.albums)
        result <- do.call(rbind, df)
        colnames(result)[2]<-"Artist Name"
        result
    })

   # Observes and updates album selection part
   observe({
        albums <- unique(result_final()$`Album Name`)
        updateSelectInput(session, "selectinputid",
                          label = "selectinputid",
                          choices = albums,
                          selected = albums[1])
    })

    output$result <- renderTable({
        spotify<-result_final()$`Album IDs`
        df <- lapply(spotify, get.tracks)
        result <- do.call(rbind, df)
        result_final2<-result
        names(result_final2) <- c("ID", "NAME", "ARTIST ID", "ARTIST NAME")
        final<-result_final2
        final1<-final[!duplicated(final), ]    
        final2 <- final1[!duplicated(final1[2:5]),]
        colnames(final2)[5]<-"Album ID"    
        with_album_name<-left_join(final2,result_final(), by=c("Album ID" = "Album IDs"))
        with_album_name <- with_album_name[,-c(6:7)] 
        randomVals2 <- eventReactive(input$goButton1, input$selectinputid)
        target <- c(randomVals2())
        result_final<-filter(with_album_name, `Album Name` %in% target)
        final2<-result_final
        final2
    })
}




shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, do I put the `get.artists` before or after the `ids` variable? Would you mind putting in the full script? No need to include the ui part since that doesn't change much. Thanks for your help with this!

Comment: Thank you! Is there a reason, why the side panel gets cutoff to only half the page with this new version?

Comment: @NickKnauer I can't see it on my machine... It shouldn't, because it's a ui thing and I didn't change much there. If my solution solved your problem you can accept my answer.

Comment: @PoGibas :  Why did you need to wrap an `eventReactive()` with a `reactive()` function in your starting lines of the server.R code? Isn't the `eventReactive` contect not a good enough reactive context?